# How to abort or cancel LSB job on boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

My Pi gets stuck on boot-up with the message "A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interfaces (timer / no limit)". The timer keeps counting up, bot the job never completes, and thus the Pi never finishes booting. How can I abort this process so that the Pi continues booting?

Backstory: I'm running Raspbian Jessie on a Pi B, and after the first successful boot, I wanted to configure the wifi dongle for my home network. Since the home network does not broadcast its SSID, I couldn't use the Network Prefs UI. I tried editing some config files, but now the Pi is stuck on boot.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the esc key?

Comment: @joan - Yes. Esc does not stop the timer or the asterisks.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect ethernet it should work. You'll need to make sure that the file, `/etc/network/interfaces`, has the line `auto lo iface lo inet loopback`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that pulling my wifi dongle allows the Pi to boot. My problem stems from having to have 2 setups, one for school, the other for my out dated home network. Since my wifi can't connect until I enable it, it hangs.
A poor work around, but its what I am currently working on, hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi part of the Stack Exchange.  Any chance that you can update your home network? 8-)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can improve boot time by disabling dhcpcd (DHCP client that was doing DHCP Discover on all interfaces). Use this: sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd

FYI: dhcp client will still work on a per-interface basis according to /etc/network/interfaces which may contain an entry such as "iface eth0 inet dhcp"